# How to subset R dataframe based on string matching?

Tags: r

Assume the dataframe is like below:

```
   Name Score 
1  John  10
2  John   2
3  James  5
```

I would like to compute the mean of all the Score values which has John's name.

Comment: `mean(df[df$Name == "John", "Score"])` where `df` is the data

Answer (score 1):

You can easily perform a mean of every person's score with `aggregate`:

```
> aggregate(Score ~ Name, data=d, FUN=mean)
   Name Score
1 James     5
2  John     6
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr`:

For each name:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(Name) %>%
  summarise(Value=mean(Score))

   Name Value
1 James     5
2  John     6
```

Filtering:

```
filter(df, Name=="John") %>%
  group_by(Name) %>%
  summarise(Value=mean(Score))

  Name Value
1 John     6
```

Using `sqldf`:

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("SELECT Name, avg(Score) AS Score
      FROM df GROUP BY Name")

   Name Score
1 James     5
2  John     6
```

Filtering:

```
sqldf("SELECT Name, avg(Score) AS Score
      FROM df 
      WHERE Name LIKE 'John'")

  Name Score
1 John     6
```